# css override in bootstrap 3.3.4 not working when eliminating background color in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I can change the background color of the navbar in Bootstrap 3.3.4 to any color I would like by simply using:

```
.navbar {background-color: whatever color I want;}
```

except for when I want to remove the color by using:

```
.navbar {background-color: transparent;}
```

I've tried numerous ways to get the this done and it works just fine in previous versions of bootstrap is this a known issue or is there a new class that makes the background in the navbar transparent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hilmy Productions</title>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link  href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="less_css/hilmy_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
    background: url(../imgs/Hilmy/Hilmy_Sign_FINAL.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
    background-color:transparent;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: kindly put your html code, as i have no problem in changing .navbar to any color i want or make sure you are not using 2 classes navbar navbar-default or navbar navbar-inverse if that is the case than you have to change background color for navbar-default or navbar-inverse whichever is in your <nav> tag.

Comment: Added the html and css it's nothing crazy just a basic image background with default nav you can find on the bootstrap site.

Comment: i have checked default nav from getbootstrap.com and if thats the case than you have to change background color with .navbar-default not with navbar and if you are putting your style before loading bootstrap.min.css than you have to put !important as well in your code .navbar-default{ background-color: #whatever you want }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vrnb47qt/

Comment: I can change the actual color just fine, but I don't want there to be any color.

Comment: @Dmitriy the background still displays white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:

- change `background-color` of  `body`. Making the body of the page transparent will make the underlying image visible. By default body has a background-color of white.

  ```css
  html {
    background: url(http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/simple-wallpaper-26.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    /*by default white*/
  }
  .navbar {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }

  /*just to put emphasis on the changes*/
  /*.container-fluid {
    border-bottom: solid;
  }
  */
  a {
    color: black !important;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  ```

**OR**

- instead of using the background property on to the html tag put it in the body of your page.

  ```css
  body {
    background: url(http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/simple-wallpaper-26.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .navbar {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }

  /*just to put emphasis on the changes*/
  /*.container-fluid {
    border-bottom: solid;
  }
  */
  a {
    color: black !important;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  ```

**The Second option is more preferable.** 

*Ignore the properties added to `.container-fluid` class and `a` element, they are there just to make the changes more apparent.*

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know if I would've ever figured that out. Why exactly do you need to add those attributes to the .container-fluid and body?

Comment: added explanation to my answer, again styles on `.container-fluid` is not necessary.